# I used a bash command in home and vim-pathogen stopped working

Tags: linux, bash, vim, pathogen

I used this command

```
for f in *; do mv "$f" `echo $f | tr ' ' '_'`; done
```

to remove whitespaces in /home/user and now vim tells me this:

```
Error detected while processing /home/user/.vimrc:
line    2:
E117: Unknown function: pathogen#infect
E15: Invalid expression: pathogen#infect()
line    3:
E117: Unknown function: pathogen#helptags
line   10:
E185: Cannot find color scheme 'solarized'
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

can this be related?
I already reinstalled pathogen but everythink seems fine for me.

Comment: Is this related? Answer: No. Pathogen only looks for files in `~/.vim` (and other places vim stores files (i.e. runtime path)). It doesn't care about anything in your home directory. How did you install pathogen because it does not appear to be installed properly. It should have been installed to `~/.vim/autoload/pathogen.vim`

Comment: Where are the pathogen installed files living? Did you perhaps have a link to them in some non-`.vim` location in `.vim` that had a space that might have been broken by this?

Comment: What are lines 2, 3, 10 in .vimrc?

Comment: lines 2,3 and 10 pretty much already stand there but Etan was right, the link which points to .vim somhow pointed on itself so vim couldnt load pathogen because the it couldnt find the folder. Thanks for zour help!

Answer (score 0):

If pathogen expects to find (not dot-) files in your home directory with spaces in them, this would definitely confuse it. I don't know anything about pathogen, but I sure hope it doesn't expect that. Look for pathogen- or vim-related files that may have been renamed.